# Connect Netgear router R7000 to WAN-side using its Wi-Fi antennas, LAN-side using its Ethernet ports

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, home-networking

I have purchased an R7000 router specifically for the purpose. I wish to connect Netgear router R7000 to WAN-side using its Wi-Fi antennas, LAN-side using its Ethernet ports.  This is residential.  Comcast Wi-Fi is the ISP. There is no coax line available, which you may imagine is much like a hotel or other travelling arrangement for internet access; however, this is going to be stationary and permanent, not traveling or temporary. There will be paid access to this ISP so please do not suggest or otherwise discuss non-paid access of any kind, and thank you for cooperation.

Did you notice something strange?  "WAN-side using its Wi-Fi antennas, LAN-side using its Ethernet ports"   Did he mean that?  Yes he did. It's crucial. Thanks!

The user documentation is showing me in diagrams or describing in text, only wired-WAN-side setups, to the best of my understanding.  I am unable to discern if the Netgear-supplied firmware on this router is able to support the requirement.  Maybe it is, maybe it isn't; I cannot discern.

https://www.netgear.com/support/product/R7000#docs

Strictly as a fallback to the OEM-supplied firmware, I am willing to re-flash using aftermarket firmware, you name the package (I can wildly guess but I'm not going to) but again, not as first recourse please.  Please specify detailed operation for achieving this specific requirement with this router and the specific aftermarket firmware, if known.  Again, this is fallback strategy only. Thanks!

Not absolutely clear yet but this device appears (that is, seems) to have two Wi-Fi radios.  There are several ethernet NICs built-in, of course, and of the wired NICs there is one WAN side port and four LAN side ports, per documentation. I imagine firmware can adjust the purpose and usage of radios and NICs to some extent (what extent exactly, I do not know).

This will be a second ISP gateway for the LAN of the residential location. I will specify the gateway of choice (since there will be two available once this is working correctly) manually at each host; nothing fancy is needed like load balancing automation.   Although later I can imagine adding round-robin etc, the basic connnectivity is the priority issue. Thank you.

So... how to Connect Netgear router R7000 to WAN-side using its Wi-Fi antennas, LAN-side using its Ethernet ports?  Thanks!!!

You can assume I can read and speak software engineering, but not network engineering much. Ubuntu hosts are available for experimentation in this LAN. Hope this helps for our comms going forward.

Comment: I disagree that it is off topic to superuser forum of stackexchange.  Theres a similar question here but I have not ascertained if it is the same question yet. https://superuser.com/questions/1194879/connect-a-wireless-lan-to-a-wan-wirelessly?rq=1 The network engineering forum also said it is off topic.  You guys keep punting other people's efforts for very weak reasons.

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot easily take a wireless access point (which is what this is, as well as a router) and tell it to connect to a ISP's provided wireless network.

You need to ascertain exactly what kind of service Comcast offer as most of the time they'll provide a device for you to use to connect. Once you have this you can figure out what hardware you need to connect to it, but I very much doubt you'll be able to use this router as a client to connect to Comcast.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion.  As I said, I actually have connected in the past to this ISP's provided wireless network, however it was using my personal computer device, at their invitation.  They are inviting everyone to sign up to use it with customer provided client computers. They did not provide me with a device.  Maybe the way forward is to do that again, gather the information, and put that information into my router this time instead of my PC. "Bridge Mode" is what another answerer suggested trying in my router.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your router to bridge mode. [Here](https://kb.netgear.com/24105/What-is-bridge-mode-and-how-do-I-set-it-up-on-my-Nighthawk-router) you can read in Netgear KB how to do this.

> To set up bridge mode:
>
> 1. Make a note of the WiFi settings of the other router to which this router will connect.
>      You need to know the SSID, WiFi security mode, wireless password, and operating frequency (either 2.4 GHz or 5 GHz).
> 2. Launch a web browser from a computer or mobile device that is connected to the network of the router that will run in bridge mode.
> 3. Type http://www.routerlogin.net.
>      A login screen displays.
> 4. Enter the router user name and password.
>      The user name is **admin**. The default password is **password**. 
>      The user name and password are case-sensitive.
>      The BASIC Home screen displays.
> 5. Click ADVANCED > Advanced Setup > Wireless Bridge.
>      The Wireless Bridge page displays.
> 6. Select the **Enable Bridge Mode** checkbox.
> 7. Click the **Setup Bridge Mode Wireless Settings** button.
> 8. Enter the settings of the other router:
>
>    1. Select the wireless network frequency (**2.4 GHz** or **5 GHz**)
>         For 802.11ac mode, select **5 GHz**.
>    2. In the **Name (SSID)** field, enter the wireless network name (SSID).
>    3. In the Security Option section, select the WiFi security mode of the other router.
>    4. If prompted, type the passphrase (the WiFi password that you use to connect with WiFi to the router).
> 9. Click the **Apply** button.
>      The settings for the other router are saved and the Advanced Wireless Settings page displays.
> 10. Click the **Apply** button on the Advanced Wireless Settings page.
>       Your settings are saved.

Comment: I am not on other router's LAN, so how will I find SSID, Wifi security mode, wireless password?  I do not have physical access to that other router at all. But In the past I have connected for so-called free trial mode, while using a personal computer and in their web page, I entered my email address as they requested.  So now I have a router to be the other router's client, instead of a PC, and I would like to sign up on their web page again but of course an R7000 has no web browser that I know of.  I expect troubles here. But anyways, I'll go see what happens.  THanks for the info.

Comment: In such case I do not know a way to do this. Maybe you can ask ISP for normal WiFi password.